# Android Studio get location from Google Maps api

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I am making an Android app where I am asking the user to move the marker on Google maps to get the location of a place they would like to share with me. How do I get the lat and long of the marker where it is placed on the map?

Comment: LatLng markerLocation = marker.getPosition(); provides you location. Try this

Comment: I sugest using the Google Places API for this purpose: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/

Comment: Please consider adding the code that you have tried so far otherwise it attract down voting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this code to get the centered lat & long then use it the way you like

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
              @Override
                public void onCameraMove() {
        System.out.println(mMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude);
        System.out.println(mMap.getCameraPosition().target.longitude);
        }
      });
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar implementation in my android app where the user can drag the marker to different locations and get the details of the location like latitude,longitude,address.

**MapActivity**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocomplete;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class TestDragMarker extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private static String TAG = "MAP LOCATION";
    Context mContext;
    TextView mLocationMarkerText;
    private LatLng mCenterLatLong;

    private AddressResultReceiver mResultReceiver;

    protected String mAddressOutput;
    protected String mAreaOutput;
    protected String mCityOutput;
    protected String mStateOutput;
    EditText mLocationAddress;
    TextView mLocationText;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE = 1;
    Toolbar mToolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_drag_marker);
        mContext = this;
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mLocationMarkerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationMarkertext);
        mLocationAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Address);
       // mLocationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Locality);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
      //  setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
     //   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

      //  getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));


       /* mLocationText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                openAutocompleteActivity();

            }


        });  */
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mResultReceiver = new AddressResultReceiver(new Handler());

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            // If this check succeeds, proceed with normal processing.
            // Otherwise, prompt user to get valid Play Services APK.
            if (!AppUtils.isLocationEnabled(mContext)) {
                // notify user
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                dialog.setMessage("Location not enabled!");
                dialog.setPositiveButton("Open location settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Location not supported in this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnMapReady");
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                Log.d("Camera postion change" + "", cameraPosition + "");
                mCenterLatLong = cameraPosition.target;


                mMap.clear();

                try {

                    Location mLocation = new Location("");
                    mLocation.setLatitude(mCenterLatLong.latitude);
                    mLocation.setLongitude(mCenterLatLong.longitude);

                    startIntentService(mLocation);
                    mLocationMarkerText.setText("Lat : " + mCenterLatLong.latitude + "," + "Long : " + mCenterLatLong.longitude);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
//        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
//        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
//
//        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
//        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
//        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
//        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            changeMap(mLastLocation);
            Log.d(TAG, "ON connected");

        } else
            try {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                        mGoogleApiClient, this);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {
            LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        try {
            if (location != null)
                changeMap(location);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }


    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        try {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                //finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void changeMap(Location location) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Reaching map" + mMap);


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
            LatLng latLong;


            latLong = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(latLong).zoom(19f).tilt(70).build();

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            mLocationMarkerText.setText("Lat : " + location.getLatitude() + "," + "Long : " + location.getLongitude());
            startIntentService(location);


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    }


    /**
     * Receiver for data sent from FetchAddressIntentService.
     */
    class AddressResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
        public AddressResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

        /**
         * Receives data sent from FetchAddressIntentService and updates the UI in MainActivity.
         */
        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {

            // Display the address string or an error message sent from the intent service.
            mAddressOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.RESULT_DATA_KEY);

            mAreaOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_AREA);

            mCityOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_CITY);
            mStateOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_STREET);

            displayAddressOutput();

            // Show a toast message if an address was found.
            if (resultCode == AppUtils.LocationConstants.SUCCESS_RESULT) {
                //  showToast(getString(R.string.address_found));


            }


        }

    }

    /**
     * Updates the address in the UI.
     */
    protected void displayAddressOutput() {
        //  mLocationAddressTextView.setText(mAddressOutput);
        try {
            if (mAreaOutput != null)
                // mLocationText.setText(mAreaOutput+ "");

                mLocationAddress.setText(mAddressOutput);
            //mLocationText.setText(mAreaOutput);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an intent, adds location data to it as an extra, and starts the intent service for
     * fetching an address.
     */
    protected void startIntentService(Location mLocation) {
        // Create an intent for passing to the intent service responsible for fetching the address.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FetchAddressIntentService.class);

        // Pass the result receiver as an extra to the service.
        intent.putExtra(AppUtils.LocationConstants.RECEIVER, mResultReceiver);

        // Pass the location data as an extra to the service.
        intent.putExtra(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA, mLocation);

        // Start the service. If the service isn't already running, it is instantiated and started
        // (creating a process for it if needed); if it is running then it remains running. The
        // service kills itself automatically once all intents are processed.
        startService(intent);
    }


    private void openAutocompleteActivity() {
        try {
            // The autocomplete activity requires Google Play Services to be available. The intent
            // builder checks this and throws an exception if it is not the case.
            Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                    .build(this);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            // Indicates that Google Play Services is either not installed or not up to date. Prompt
            // the user to correct the issue.
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, e.getConnectionStatusCode(),
                    0 /* requestCode */).show();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            // Indicates that Google Play Services is not available and the problem is not easily
            // resolvable.
            String message = "Google Play Services is not available: " +
                    GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorString(e.errorCode);

            Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called after the autocomplete activity has finished to return its result.
     */
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Check that the result was from the autocomplete widget.
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the user's selected place from the Intent.
                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(mContext, data);

                // TODO call location based filter


                LatLng latLong;


                latLong = place.getLatLng();

                //mLocationText.setText(place.getName() + "");

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(latLong).zoom(19f).tilt(70).build();

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


            }


        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(mContext, data);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Indicates that the activity closed before a selection was made. For example if
            // the user pressed the back button.
        }
    }


}
```

**XML Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:hint="Address"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container_toolbar">

        <fragment
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.sample.sishin.maplocation.MapsActivity" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/locationMarker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/locationMarkertext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_map"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minWidth="250dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:text=" Set your Location "
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageMarker"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/add_marker" />
        </LinearLayout>



    </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Address Fetcher Service**

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;



public class FetchAddressIntentService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = "FetchAddressIS";


    protected ResultReceiver mReceiver;

    /**
     * This constructor is required, and calls the super IntentService(String)
     * constructor with the name for a worker thread.
     */
    public FetchAddressIntentService() {
        // Use the TAG to name the worker thread.
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String errorMessage = "";

        mReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(AppUtils.LocationConstants.RECEIVER);


        if (mReceiver == null) {
            Log.wtf(TAG, "No receiver received. There is nowhere to send the results.");
            return;
        }
        // Get the location passed to this service through an extra.
        Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA);



        if (location == null) {
            errorMessage = getString(R.string.no_location_data_provided);
            Log.wtf(TAG, errorMessage);
            deliverResultToReceiver(AppUtils.LocationConstants.FAILURE_RESULT, errorMessage, null);
            return;
        }



        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {

            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                    location.getLatitude(),
                    location.getLongitude(),
                    // In this sample, we get just a single address.
                    1);
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            // Catch network or other I/O problems.
            errorMessage = getString(R.string.service_not_available);
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage, ioException);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
            // Catch invalid latitude or longitude values.
            errorMessage = getString(R.string.invalid_lat_long_used);
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage + ". " +
                    "Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() +
                    ", Longitude = " + location.getLongitude(), illegalArgumentException);
        }

        // Handle case where no address was found.
        if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
            if (errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
                errorMessage = getString(R.string.no_address_found);
                Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
            }
            deliverResultToReceiver(AppUtils.LocationConstants.FAILURE_RESULT, errorMessage, null);
        } else {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            ArrayList<String> addressFragments = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                addressFragments.add(address.getAddressLine(i));

            }
            deliverResultToReceiver(AppUtils.LocationConstants.SUCCESS_RESULT,
                    TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"), addressFragments), address);


        }
    }


    private void deliverResultToReceiver(int resultCode, String message, Address address) {
        try {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.RESULT_DATA_KEY, message);

            bundle.putString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_AREA, address.getSubLocality());

            bundle.putString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_CITY, address.getLocality());
            bundle.putString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_STREET, address.getAddressLine(0));

            mReceiver.send(resultCode, bundle);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```